# Babel 6 CLI: Unexpected token export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to run Babel through it's CLI using `babel-node` but I keep getting the `Unexpected token export` error. I understand that Babel 6 is all about plugins and that I need to set the plugin through `.babelrc` but it doesn't seem to work properly.

So here are my questions:

- Should I be using the [syntax-export-extensions plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-export-extensions/#usage)? I've also tried using the alternative method which is [setting the plugin through `package.json`](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#use-via-package-json) but still no luck.
- Also, does Babel 6's CLI have a global `.babelrc` option? It seems tedious if I have to install the plugins for every project that requires it...

For those who are curious of what I'm trying to export, then here is the class:

```
'use strict';

class Factorial {
  static solve (num) {
    if(num === 0) return 1;
    else return num * Factorial.solve(num - 1);
  }
}

console.log(Factorial.solve(5))

export default Factorial;
```

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't use a class if it has static methods only. Either use an object or in this case, simple have a single function.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the tip, I'm just used to using classes since I come from a C++/C#/Java background ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to get started is to use a **preset**.

First let's install our dependencies:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

Then add a `build` script to your package.json that runs Babel: (this is important because it will use your local version of `babel-cli` instead of a globally installed one)

```
"build": "babel input.js"
```

Your `package.json` should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.x.x",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.x.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel input.js -o compiled.js"
  }
}
```

Finally you want to update your local `.babelrc` like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Then you run `npm run build` and you're all set to go.

> Also, does Babel 6's CLI have a global .babelrc option? It seems tedious if I have to install the plugins for every project that requires it...

That's a bad idea as it means you can't ever update it without updating every single one of your projects code. Having local versions means this potential error is less likely to occur.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that presets exists and did use it but it seems like the `import` keyword doesn't work? Would you know anything about this issue?

Comment: Might be a problem with your version of Babel. There were some early issues, try updating and if that doesn't work stop by the Slack channel for support. https://slack.babeljs.io/

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error, but my webpack/babel configs looked correct. By trial and error, I replaced `export myFunction` with `export default myFunction` and the error got resolved.

---

Later, I realized that the correct way of exporting is `export {myFunction}`. I implemented it and everything works fine.