# How to add multiple style attributes to a react element?

Tags: css, reactjs

How would I go about adding multiple style attributes to my React element?

Some of the components in my app are using the same styles throughout with minor variations in styles. I am trying to accomplish something along the lines of `<div style={this.styles.mainStyle, this.styles.variationInStyle}></div>`.

These styles are in a file called styles.js hence the `this.styles.x`. It works with only one style in it. The closest I found to this solution was in a [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/33vbho/is_it_possible_to_use_multiple_styles_within/). The solution was `<div style={$.extend({}, style1, style2)}></div>` but of course, it doesn't work nor does the variation `<div style={style1, style2)}></div>`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! I will also be posting in Reddit and the Reactiflux Discord group if the answer should come from either source, I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 37):

`style` is just an Object, with css value turn to camelCase, so you could use any way to merge two object, and it should work.

**ES6:** `style={Object.assign({}, style1, style2)}`

**ES7:** `style={{...style1, ...style2}}`

**lodash:** `style={_.merge({}, style1, style2)}`

Comment: How would that work if these styles are in a separate sheet from the component it is being added to? In order to access the styles, I have to type this.styles.style1} 

Also, the syntax on your ES6 example has an unclosed parenthesis after `.assign`

Comment: I don't get it. What problem are you facing? it just and object, what prevent you from merging two javascript object? If it from two stylesheet then `const style1 = require('./style1.css'); const style2 = require('./style2.css');`
Or if it's inline style then it's already an object, isn't it?

Comment: In React Native you can use an array inside curly brackets: `style={[style1, style2]}`

Comment: @SteffoDimfelt `Failed to set an indexed property [0] on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Indexed property setter is not supported.`

Answer (score 10):

as @michealmuxica said, the style prop is is just a JS object with camel casing for the keys. So you can set your style on your components as such:

```
<MyComponent style={{height:"100%", marginLeft:"70%"}} />
```

I prefer to create another JS file per component to contain the style objects, then import them into the component's file. I feel like this keeps the code more clean and modular:

```
//in MyComponentStyles.js
var style = {
    base:{
        height:"100%",
        width: "100%",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto"
    },
    //...other styles...
};
export default styles;


//in MyComponent.js
import {default as MyComponentStyles} from "./<path to styles>/MyComponentStyles.js;

var App = React.createClass({ 
    render: function() {
        return ( <MyComponent style={MyComponentStyles.base} /> );
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an 'Unexpected token export' error with this

Comment: The answer for this question may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448675/babel-6-cli-unexpected-token-export

I'm using babel and have been caught up on the presets before, too.