# How can I set the z-index for this select?

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I would like to set the z-index of the following component :

```
import React from 'react';
import chroma from 'chroma-js';

import { colourOptions } from './docs/data';
import Select from 'react-select';

const colourStyles = {
  control: styles => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
  option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: isDisabled
        ? null
        : isSelected
        ? data.color
        : isFocused
        ? color.alpha(0.1).css()
        : null,
      color: isDisabled
        ? '#ccc'
        : isSelected
        ? chroma.contrast(color, 'white') > 2
          ? 'white'
          : 'black'
        : data.color,
      cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',

      ':active': {
        ...styles[':active'],
        backgroundColor: !isDisabled && (isSelected ? data.color : color.alpha(0.3).css()),
      },
    };
  },
  multiValue: (styles, { data }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: color.alpha(0.1).css(),
    };
  },
  multiValueLabel: (styles, { data }) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: data.color,
  }),
  multiValueRemove: (styles, { data }) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: data.color,
    ':hover': {
      backgroundColor: data.color,
      color: 'white',
    },
  }),
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[0], colourOptions[1]]}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    styles={colourStyles}
  />
);
```

I found this solution :

```
styles={{menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999, colourStyles })}}
```

instead of

```
styles={colourStyles}
```

But I lose all the colors...

Could you help me please ?

Here is the code :

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-noether-1ee0v?file=/example.js:0-1531

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you used `styles={{colourStyles}}` instead of `styles={colourStyles}`, then the app would also lose the colors. This is because it is not expanded as it should. However, `styles={{...colourStyles}}` would work. Read more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do).

So this bit of code should fix your problem:

**[example.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/zindextest-iwf15?file=/example.js)**

```
export default () => (
  <Select
    [your other props],
    styles={{
      ...colourStyles, 
      ...{control: styles => ({ ...styles, zIndex: 9999})},
    }}
  />
);
```

where the two objects `colourStyles` and `{zIndex: 9999}` were merged (in ES6 compatible syntax, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846352/how-to-add-multiple-style-attributes-to-a-react-element/34846855) for different ways to do this). Alternatively you can just append `zIndex: 9999` right behind `backgroundColor: 'white'` within the `colourStyles` constant.

Upon inspection you can see it works:

[image: Inspected element has applied z-index.]

Comment: It does not work unfirtunately, I would like to add the following property : `zIndex: 9999 !important` but I don't know how to do this ....

Comment: It does work, see [this Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zindextest-iwf15?file=/example.js). If you inspect the element you will indeed see that the `z-index` was modified accordingly. So why would you want to use `!important`?