# Import React in Node.js throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, server-side-rendering, babel-node

I'm trying to implement SSR with Node.js and React following this example https://github.com/babel/example-node-server as advised in the official Babel docs here http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node

For development, I'm using `babel-node`; for production I want to transpile my server with babel and run it with `node`:

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./dist/server/index.js",
  "dev:server": "nodemon ./src/server/index.js -x babel-node",
  "build:server": "babel ./src/server -d ./dist/server --copy-files -s inline"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

The server is written with ES6 syntax:

#### src/server/index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import './config'
import Express from 'express'
import bootstrap from './bootstrap'

const app = Express()
bootstrap(app)

export default app
```

Then in some route I import my React components to render it into HTML on request:

#### src/server/routes/admin.js

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from 'react-router'
import configureStore from '../../../src/admin/store'
import routes from '../../../src/admin/routes'
import Root from '../../../src/admin/containers/Root'
// etc.
```

The error is thrown when server tries to import React components

```
./src/admin/store/index.js:11
export default configureStore
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I tried using `babel-register` in the server, and it works, but it's not recommended to use it in production mode, so I would rather not do it.

Also, when inspecting the built server code, I find:

#### dist/server/routes/admin.js

```
var _store = require('../../../src/admin/store');
```

It means that it's still referencing the `src` folder. Ideally I'd like to somehow incorporate those modules into the built server code, so I could safely remove the `src` folder from the production environment, leaving only `dist`.

### Edit

Different from [Babel 6 CLI: Unexpected token export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448675/babel-6-cli-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: not sure, check this may be solve your issue [Babel 6 CLI: Unexpected token export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448675/babel-6-cli-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: @MayankShukla unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are transpiling only `./src/server` and not `./src/admin`. Then in `./src/server` you have `export` keyword not translated by Babel and the `export` keyword is not supported by Node - to see why, see those answers:

- [Is it ok to use Babel npm package for node.js server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442290/is-it-ok-to-use-babel-npm-package-for-node-js-server-application/42442403#42442403)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)
- [Exporting Node module from promise result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279796/exporting-node-module-from-promise-result/41279904#41279904)

You need to transpile all of the code that uses syntax that is not natively supported by Node, not only some of it.

Adding a script like this to your package.json might help, depending on how your `./src` and `./dist` is organized:

```
"build:all": "babel ./src -d ./dist --copy-files -s inline"
```

Of course not knowing what you have in `./src` apart from `server` and `admin` it's hard to give you a specific solution - but that's a good direction to start from.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was missing in my config. In `./src` there are `server`, two react entry points (one for `client` and one for `admin`) and `styles`, so I've also added `--ignore ./src/styles` into the build command. Works like a charm 